# Jquery Mouseover and Mouseleave Tooltips (delay and how to cancel if mouse is moved before SetTimeOut)

Tags: jquery, settimeout, delay, mouseover, mouseleave

O.k. so in a $(document).ready(function() {...}

I have code that binds an event to all links with a class of .user_tooltip which makes an ajax call to get the user's info.

It works well. It displays the tooltip next to the link no matter where it is in the page.

Unfortunately I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to add a delay and a cancel on the delay when the mouse leaves the link before the timeout.

Basically the tool tips display immediately, and it's just annoying and unusable.

How do I add a delay so the ajax doesn't fire until...500ms of mouseover/mouseenter and cancels if mouseleave happens before the 500ms?

I've tried everything I can think of and it's just not working.

Code:

```
//user_tooltips
    $(document).on('mouseover', '.user_tooltip', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var user_tooltip_link = e.target.href;
      user_tooltip_link = user_tooltip_link.split("/");
      user_tooltip_name = user_tooltip_link[user_tooltip_link.length-1];
      var user_tooltip_username = $("#user_tooltip_username").html();
      if(user_tooltip_username != user_tooltip_name){
        var user_tooltip_ajax_request = $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
          url: '/user_tooltip_info/' + user_tooltip_name
        });
      }

      displayDiv("user_tooltip", getLeft(this.id) + 45, getTop(this.id));
    });

    $(document).on('mouseleave', '#user_tooltip', function(e){
      $("#user_tooltip").hide();
    });

   $(document).on("click", function(){
    $("#user_tooltip").hide();
  });
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout` to delay the AJAX. And if they mouseout, use `clearTimeout` to cancel it.

Comment: Yes, but how? Introducing another function(){...} pretty much breaks everything. Sorry to be so dense, but I've hit the point where I just can't think clearly about what to do : (

Comment: I don't understand the AJAX code, it has no `success:` function that displays the result.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The display is handled in a js.erb (rails) which displays the tool_tip, that's why I want to delay the actual ajax call. Not the prettiest code, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Start a timer in the `mouseover` handler to display the AJAX call. Then cancel the timer in the `mouseleave` handler.

Use an arrow function for the timeout so that `this` will be captured.

```js
let tooltip_interval;

$(document).on('mouseover', '.user_tooltip', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var user_tooltip_link = e.target.href;
  user_tooltip_link = user_tooltip_link.split("/");
  user_tooltip_name = user_tooltip_link[user_tooltip_link.length - 1];
  var user_tooltip_username = $("#user_tooltip_username").html();
  if (user_tooltip_username != user_tooltip_name) {
    tooltip_interval = setTimeout(() => {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
        },
        url: '/user_tooltip_info/' + user_tooltip_name
      });

      displayDiv("user_tooltip", getLeft(this.id) + 45, getTop(this.id));
    }, 500);
  }


});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.user_tooltip', function(e) {
  clearTimeout(tooltip_interval);
  $("#user_tooltip").hide();
});

$(document).on("click", function() {
  $("#user_tooltip").hide();
});
```

Comment: You awesome! I was banging my head against the walls trying to figure this out. I've looked up everything and none of it worked and I knew I was totally burnt on trying to solve it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Unfortunately after the first delay and load it goes right back to displaying immediately : ( I hope I can find a work around...

Comment: I can't think of a reason why that happens. It should call `setTimeout()` every time.

Comment: What does `displayDiv()` do? Maybe that should be part of the timeout.

Comment: Yeah I just tried it...unfortunately when it's in the timeout block it doesn't display next to the link - it's always at the top of the page. Basically displayDiv get's the left and top coordinates of the link and uses old school document.getElementById(target_div).style.left/top to set where the tooltip should be located.

Comment: Did you get the change to an arrow function so that `this.id` will be available in the callback?

Comment: No. You're WAY above my head on that one...where should I put the arrow function?

Comment: Where it is in my code. `setTimeout(() => {`. That was my last edit, you might have copied before I did that.

Comment: It worked! I'm going to need to read up on the arrow function. This is really good now - it doesn't make the ajax call, the tool tip is in the right place and it doesn't display until it's loaded. Thank you again!